# The level of a High Priest

Tags: kohen-priest, mamzer, kohen-gadol

[Horayot 13a](https://www.sefaria.org/Horayot.13a.17?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) - "But if there were a mamzer who is a Torah scholar and a High Priest who is an ignoramus, a mamzer who is a Torah scholar precedes a High Priest who is an ignoramus, as Torah wisdom surpasses all else."

How can a person who is ignoramus can be elected as a High Priest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See (for example) [Yoma 8b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Yoma.8b.7?lang=bi), where it is explained that during the Second Temple period the office of the High Priest was sold to the highest bidder, such that an ignorant High Priest was, unfortunately, not impossible by any means.

See also [Mishnah Yoma 1:3](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Yoma.1.3?lang=bi) where the possibility is raised of a High Priest who is not familiar with the details of the Yom Kippur service in the Temple, as well as [1:6](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Yoma.1.6?lang=bi) which deals with an illiterate High Priest.

Comment: Surprised learning this one. Thank you @Joel K